# Ubuntu 13.04 only detects one of my processors

Tags: 13.04, cpu

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 18
model       : 1
model name  : AMD A6-3670 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x3000027
cpu MHz     : 2781.169
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 6
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat
pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 
3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm 
cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs kinit 
wdt arat hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
bogomips    : 5562.33
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps hwpstate
```

I dont understand how to fix this :( please help if possible

Answer (score 0):

Issue `top` on terminal and press <kbd>1</kbd> - you will see all 4 cores at work. It has to be something wrong in kernel cpu boot detection...